# inherit widget passing parameter doesnt retain value

Tags: flutter

i have a situation where i have my  main class and an inherit widget.  when i wrap my main class within the inherit class and pass a parameter, for some reason the inherit class is not retaining the value of the parameter i passed. below is my code

main class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finsec/widget/drawer_widget.dart';
import 'package:finsec/widget/inherited_month_year.dart';
import 'package:finsec/screens/income/second_fragment.dart';
import 'package:finsec/screens/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:finsec/screens/transaction/transaction_list.dart';
import 'package:finsec/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:finsec/utils/strings.dart';
import 'package:month_picker_dialog/month_picker_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:finsec/utils/localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:finsec/model/month_year.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp( initialDate: DateTime.now()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = home;
  final DateTime initialDate;

  const MyApp({Key key, @required this.initialDate}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  DateTime selectedDate, prevSelectedDate;
  String monthName1;
  int monthNumber, year;
  MonthYear monthYear;

  getDrawerItemWidget(int pos, String title) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return new HomeScreen ();
      case 1:
        return new SecondFragment();
      case 2:
        return new TransactionList(
          outstanding: totalOutstanding,
          received_or_paid:
          totalReceived, transactionType: title,);
      case 3:
        return new TransactionList(
          outstanding: totalOutstanding,
          received_or_paid: totalPaid,
          transactionType: title,);
      default:
        return new Text("Error");
    }
  }

  String titleAppBar = home;
  int tabIndex = 0;
  double elevation = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      titleAppBar = widget.title;
    });
    super.initState();
    selectedDate = widget.initialDate;
  }


  void getMonthYear() {
    if(selectedDate != null) {
      monthName1 = monthNamesAbbrv[selectedDate.month];
      monthNumber = selectedDate.month;
      year = selectedDate.year;
      prevSelectedDate = selectedDate;
    }
    else {
      monthName1 = monthNamesAbbrv[prevSelectedDate.month];
      monthNumber = prevSelectedDate.month;
      year = prevSelectedDate.year;
    }

    monthYear = new MonthYear(monthNumber: monthNumber, year: year) ;
  }

  Widget homeScreen(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(titleAppBar),
        elevation: elevation,
        backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
           builder: (context) => FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: white,), //`Icon` to display
            label: Text(monthName1 + ' $year'  , style: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 18)), //`Text` to display
            onPressed: () {
             // DateTime date = new DateTime.now();
             // showMonthPicker(context: context, initialDate: date);
              showMonthPicker(
                  context: context,
                  firstDate: DateTime( DateTime.now().year - 1 , 5),
                  lastDate: DateTime( DateTime.now().year + 1, 9 ),
                  initialDate: selectedDate ?? widget.initialDate
              )
                  .then((date) => setState(() {
                selectedDate = date ;//!= null ? date : prevSelectedDate;

              }));
            },
          ),
      )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: DrawerWidget((title, index) {
        setState(() {
          titleAppBar = title;
          tabIndex = index;
        });
      }, tabIndex),
      body: getDrawerItemWidget(tabIndex, titleAppBar),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getMonthYear();


    print('MONTH');
    print(monthYear.monthNumber);
    print('YEAR');
    print(monthYear.year);
    return StateContainer(
       // monthNumber: monthNumber,
       // year: year,
        child: new MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
           GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: [
            Locale('en'),
            Locale('zh'),
            Locale('fr'),
            Locale('es'),
            Locale('de'),
            Locale('ru'),
            Locale('ja'),
            Locale('ar'),
            Locale('fa'),
          ],
          title: widget.title,
          home: homeScreen(context)
       ),
      monthYear: monthYear,
    );
  }
}
```

inherit widget class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finsec/model/month_year.dart';

class StateContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final MonthYear monthYear;

  StateContainer({@required this.child, this.monthYear});

  static StateContainerState of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(InheritedMonthYear)
    as InheritedMonthYear).data;
  }

  @override
  StateContainerState createState() => new StateContainerState();
}

class StateContainerState extends State<StateContainer> {
  MonthYear monthYear;// =new MonthYear(monthNumber: 4, year: 2012);

  void updateMonthYear({month, year}) {
    if (monthYear == null) {
      monthYear = new MonthYear(monthNumber: month, year: year);
      setState(() {
        monthYear = monthYear;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        monthYear.monthNumber = month ?? monthYear.monthNumber;
        monthYear.year = year ?? monthYear.year;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('MONTH CONTAINER');
    print(monthYear.monthNumber);
    return InheritedMonthYear(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class InheritedMonthYear extends InheritedWidget {
  final StateContainerState data;

  InheritedMonthYear({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
    @required Widget child,
  }) :  super(key: key, child: child);


  static InheritedMonthYear of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(InheritedMonthYear) as InheritedMonthYear;
  }


  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;
 // bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedMonthYear old) {
   //return monthNumber != old.monthNumber || year != old.year;
 // }
}
```

in the main class i am calling  getMonthYear() function in the build function which prints the following

```
I/flutter (23720): MONTH
I/flutter (23720): 10
I/flutter (23720): YEAR
I/flutter (23720): 2019
```

these values get store in variable monthYear which is passed to StateContainer class from the main class.  if you notice in StateContainer class, in the build function im printing the value i passed from main

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('MONTH CONTAINER');
    print(monthYear.monthNumber);
    return InheritedMonthYear(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
```

however, i get error message

```
I/flutter (23720): MONTH CONTAINER
I/flutter (23720): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23720): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StateContainer(dirty, state:
I/flutter (23720): StateContainerState#e2af1):
I/flutter (23720): The getter 'monthNumber' was called on null.
I/flutter (23720): Receiver: null
I/flutter (23720): Tried calling: monthNumber
I/flutter (23720): 
I/flutter (23720): User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (23720):   MyApp file:///C:/Users/rodrigue33/Documents/APP/finsec/lib/main.dart:15:27
I/flutter (23720): 
I/flutter (23720): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (23720): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (23720): #1      StateContainerState.build (package:finsec/widget/inherited_month_year.dart:39:21)
```

when i try to print   print(monthYear.monthNumber); it looks like monthYear is null and flutter throw error. i dont know how could this be null if i pass monthYear from the main class and i print out the values before calling StateContainer  class for verification that monthYear is not null. can someone tell me what im doing wrong?  why when  i pass value (monthYear) to StateContainer , the value is not retain but instead monthYear in StateContainer   is null? thanks  in advance

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Too bad you can't have proper line formatting in comments.

Put a check in the `of` call to see if the value is null before returning it. If it is, that means it's not finding the InhertedWidget in the tree above the context.

Comment: hi ThinkDigital,  how do i put a check?  it looks like when i pass the monthyear from main to StateContainer, i can print the value now. but when i call StateContainer.of(context) it is blank.    i need additional help

Comment: i noticed that if i assigned a value to monthYear variable inside StateContainer as this  MonthYear monthYear =new MonthYear(monthNumber: 4, year: 2012);  then the inherit widget is working but when the value is pass from another class into StateContainer constructor then inherit widget is null.  any ideas? im printing the passing value   print(widget.monthYear.monthNumber);  and it print the correct value. why inherit widget is not taking it when value is pass to constructor of the class